# Could not open a connection to SQL Server from a window apps

Tags: sql, connection

An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. [provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - could not open a connection to SQL Server.]

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server doesn't allow for remote connections. Depending if you have access or not,

follow this url http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

But, this is pretty insecure, good luck.